# Reading raw ItemTemplate Markup of ASP.Net Control

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know if it is possible to read the raw markup of an ItemTemplate from within a repeater control?

Consider the repeater below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uiReport" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#((Product)Container.DataItem).ProductName%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody></table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm attempting to read the item template in its raw string format e.g as a string that would look as below:

```
string itemTemplate = "<tr><td><%#((Product)Container.DataItem).ProductName%></td></tr>"
```

Using Reflector and looking through the call stack has lead me to the following method as per the call stack screen grab below (see first line highlighted):

[image: call stack]

I'm assuming that from within *...__BuildControl__control6()...* the raw contents of the markup in the .aspx page are read, chopped up (RegEx?) and passed as parameters to the below method:

```
System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl.SetStaticString(index, s);
```

For the Repeater control in this example the 's' (string) parameter has the value:

```
\r\n                <tr>\r\n                    <td>
```

Note the string has been split on the first instance of <%#.

An MSDN search confirms that the SetStaticString method supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databoundliteralcontrol.setstaticstring.aspx

Is there a virtual method I am missing that will allow me to get hold of the raw template markup or is my only option to read the file contents myself (code example below) and override the necessary *Render()* methods of the Control base class?

Verbose example of code that would manually read the contents of an .aspx page:

```
string rawPageMarkUp = File.ReadAllText(physicalPathOfAspxPage);
string rawItemTemplate = RegExMethodToExtractItemTemplateFromControl(controlName, rawPageMarkUp);
```

Comment: why don't you use <%# Eval("ProductName") %> ?

Comment: Because that property name isn't strongly typed with Eval. You get compile time errors if a property name is incorrect using the approach in my example. Using Eval you would find out at runtime if you've made a mistake. Besides, for my question the use of Eval or Bind doesn't matter so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be no, there isn't a virtual method that can be used to get hold of the unparsed page. The methods that handle parsing the pages/controls are made up of sealed classes and internal methods.

The solution to this problem is the alternative suggestion described in the question.

The details of the class(es) are below so that you can review the native implementation to get ideas of what the code should look like.

Starting at the below sealed class:

[System.Web.UI.PageParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageparser)

This inherits from the abstract class:

[System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrolparser)

This class inherits a method named:

```
ParseFile
```

Follow the inherited classes until you reach:

[System.Web.UI.TemplateParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templateparser)

You will find the method here that contains the starting point of reading the raw file and parsing the contents:

```
internal void ParseFile(string physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
{
    string o = (physicalPath != null) ? physicalPath : virtualPath.VirtualPathString;
    if (this._circularReferenceChecker.Contains(o))
    {
        this.ProcessError(SR.GetString("Circular_include"));
    }
    else
    {
        this._circularReferenceChecker.Add(o);
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader;
            if (physicalPath != null)
            {
                using (reader = Util.ReaderFromFile(physicalPath, base.CurrentVirtualPath))
                {
                    this.ParseReader(reader, virtualPath);
                    return;
                }
            }
            using (Stream stream = virtualPath.OpenFile())
            {
                reader = Util.ReaderFromStream(stream, base.CurrentVirtualPath);
                this.ParseReader(reader, virtualPath);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this._circularReferenceChecker.Remove(o);
        }
    }
}
```